# Paypal dynamic credentials with Permissions API

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to use the Paypal Permissions SDK: https://github.com/paypal/permissions-sdk-php

And in particular their code snippet:

```
// Pass in a dynamically created API credential object
$cred = new PPCertificateCredential("username", "password", "path-to-pem-file");
$cred->setThirdPartyAuthorization(new PPTokenAuthorization("accessToken", "tokenSecret"));
$response = $permissions->RequestPermissions($request, $cred);
```

However, I do not have an "accessToken" or "tokenSecret" and if I understand correctly, you need to use the Permissions API to retrieve those in the first place. Infinite loop???

- Am I misunderstanding something?
- or is there another way to call the API using dynamically set credentials?
- or is their documentation incorrect?

Comment: I have the same issue, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't made the permissions work 100% yet, but I have obtained the token and token_secret.

In the Permissions SDK, cd samples and do composer update. Than update your API credentials and run the samples to get the token and token_secret of third party merchant - no PEM file required there (the samples work, all code is there).

The certificate is needed later (I think, working on this now), when you need to use previously obtained permissions to create a single use authorisation in order to create a token.

BTW, I am really disappointed with PayPal documentation regarding these features. I've been having trouble setting this up for a couple of days already. And The Permissions SDK GitHub page contains bugs in samples..!